# Symfony2 trans_default_domain is not working

Tags: symfony, translation, twig

At the end of http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#twig-templates I read about

```
{% trans_default_domain "app" %}
```

to set a translation domain for a whole template. But for me it does not work. Calling

```
app/console translation:extract de --dir=src/ --output-dir=app/Resources/translations --output-format=xliff --keep
```

Just puts all messages in the messages.de.xliff file.

But if I set the domain manually for a given label like

```
{{ label.name|trans({}, 'app') }}
```

And execute the same extract command as above, then I get a new file app.de.xliff

Is there anything more to do when using `trans_default_domain`?

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you forget simple quot, 
try this instead

```
{{ 'label.name'|trans({}, 'app') }}
```

or this

```
{{ 'label.name'|trans }}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
{% trans_default_domain "app" %}
```

That's working fine, but you should clear your cache if the translation files didn't exist before to get it working.